# db.Query cause of Fatal Exception

Tags: android, sqlite

Enviroment: Android
Database: SQLite based

I have a database created with sqlite, the database contains users details such as login, password, name, surname, country. My problem is to create query which will check the login and password [ so select query ] and than allow or not to proceed.

```
public void logineSelector(String log, String pass){
String[] kolumny = new String[]{colLogin, colPassword};
Cursor cursor= sqLiteDatabase.query(Usr_TABLE, kolumny, pass, null, null, null, null);
}
```

but the this makes the whole program total mess, debug console gives me this:

```
Fatal Exception: Main
Java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
.....
```

any suggestions what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not calling the query method with the correct parameters. Check the [javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

If you're trying to find the user with the login/password that you pass into the method, you probably want to do something like:

```
Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(Usr_TABLE, kolumny,USER_COL+"= ? and "+PASS_COL + "= ?", new String[]{log,pass},null,null,null);
```

assuming that you have defined USER_COL and PASS_COL to contain the names of the columns in question.

Comment: well, the query might be ok, but the error is still the same :/

Comment: ok, I found the reason, I forgot to open to read the database <facepalm>